# npm start failing: Error: start: `react-scripts start`

Tags: node.js, npm, create-react-app

Coworker created an project with create-react-app, it works on his computer. I cloned, ran npm install, and then npm start, got the following failing error:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/Cellar/node/15.8.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v15.8.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle candyjar@0.1.0~prestart: candyjar@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle candyjar@0.1.0~start: candyjar@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle candyjar@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle candyjar@0.1.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/dzhai/Documents/workplace/tcoe-candyjar/apis/src/main/app/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/opt/icu4c/sbin:/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:/usr/local/opt/gnu-getopt/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/dzhai/Library/Python/3.7/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/opt/apache-maven/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/dzhai/Library/Python/3.7/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
9 verbose lifecycle candyjar@0.1.0~start: CWD: /Users/dzhai/Documents/workplace/tcoe-candyjar/apis/src/main/app
10 silly lifecycle candyjar@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle candyjar@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle candyjar@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: candyjar@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:378:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:378:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
14 verbose pkgid candyjar@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/dzhai/Documents/workplace/tcoe-candyjar/apis/src/main/app
16 verbose Darwin 19.6.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/15.8.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v15.8.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error candyjar@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the candyjar@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

can someone help with this? thanks

PS: I have tried removing node_modules and rerun npm install, uninstall/reinstall node, and etc.

Found this thread https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9594 which seems to indicate reinstalling node would fix the issue, but it's not working for me.

Follow-up: completely removed node with additional manual steps, e.g., as suggested here https://stackabuse.com/how-to-uninstall-node-js-from-mac-osx/, then repeat the process, then got a slightly different error log:

```
23 verbose stack Error: command failed
23 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/index.js:64:27)
23 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:378:20)
23 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
23 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
```

Comment: Is it the same if you launch with `BROWSER=none`?

Comment: sorry, new to this, do you mean running "npm start BROWSER=none", which i just did, and it's returning the same results.

Comment: More like `BROWSER=none npm start` or whatever the current way to start up CRA apps is--it's just a sanity check. There are several things that can cause startup failures; you'll probably have to search and just start plugging through them, but start w/ checking versions of everything and make sure they're aligned (e.g., NodeJS and CRA to start).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured it out after two day's of struggle, the current app is a sub-sub-project located in a path like this: main-project/sub-project1/src/main/sub-sub-project1. But there are a bunch of remnant node files (package.json and etc.) in the sub-project1 folder from another coworker's past work, and apparently I have run "npm install" and generated a node_modules/ folder there, since it's gitignored, I never realized that. This node_modules/ folder is what's causing confusions for the node commands when they are being run in the sub-sub-project1 folder, where another node_modules/ is present.

To summarize, don't have multiple node projects in this kind of linear hierarchical manner, it may cause the node commands to be confused.